# OpenCV и access violation reading location для cv::VideoCapture::open(...)

Tags: c++, opencv

Не знаю, может быть, я крайне страшно торможу, но не совсем понимаю, как исправить.

Есть некоторый класс. Скажем, называется `MyClass`. Есть `cv::VideoCapture camera;`, объявленный в `MyClass`. Класс `cv::VideoCapture` служит для захвата видео из видеофайлов и видеопотоков с видеокамер.

Есть, к примеру, в `MyClass` какой-нибудь открытый метод `camera_open();`. И есть точка входа `main`.

Вопрос заключается в следующем:

- Если в `main` непосредственно прописать `camera.open(0);`, а затем `camera.release();`, чтобы очистить, то всё хорошо;
- Если же в `main` вызвать `camera_open()`, уже в котором содержатся `camera.open(0);` и `camera.release();`, то возникает во время выполнения программы ошибка, связанная с правами доступа при чтении.

Почему и как от этого избавиться, оставив схему с вызовом метода `camera_open()`?

То есть, должно быть так:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
MyClass mc;
mc.camera_open();
return 0;
}

void MyClass::camera_open()
{
camera.open(0);
// действия
camera.release();
}
```

---

Если конкретнее, у меня сейчас так:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
MyClass mc;
mc.ComputerVision(); // это и есть абстрактный camera_open
return 0;
}

// не указан сервер, не указана директория, не указано время
void MyClass::ComputerVision()
{
if (camera_open()) Start(desktop_directory());
}

void MyClass::ComputerVision(std::string str, short mode)
{
if (mode == 0)  // указан сервер, не указана директория, не указано время
{
   if (camera_open(str)) Start(desktop_directory());
}
else            // указана директория, не указан сервер, не указано время
{
   if (camera_open()) Start(str);
}
}

// указаны сервер и директория, не указано время
void MyClass::ComputerVision(std::string server, std::string directory)
{
if (camera_open(server)) Start(directory);
}

// указано время, не указан сервер, не указана директория
void MyClass::ComputerVision(double time)
{
userTime = time;
ComputerVision();
}

// указано время и указана либо директория, либо сервер
void MyClass::ComputerVision(double time, std::string str, short mode)
{
userTime = time;
ComputerVision(str, mode);
}

// указано время, указан сервер, указана директория
void MyClass::ComputerVision(double time, std::string server, std::string directory)
{
userTime = time;
ComputerVision(server, directory);
}

// открытие камеры по умолчанию
boolean MyClass::camera_open()
{
try {
   camera.open(0);
   server = "";
}
catch (std::exception)
{
   std::cout << std::endl << "Failed to connect to your web camera";
   return false;
}
return true;
}

// открытие камеры по указанному серверу
boolean MyClass::camera_open(std::string server)
{
try {
   camera.open(server);
   this->server = server;
}
catch (std::exception)
{
   std::cout << std::endl << "Failed to connect to IP camera";
   return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Обе `camera_open(...)` приватные, остальное - публичное. Ошибка возникает на `camera.open(...);`.

Comment: Что-то тут не так, потому что ошибки с правами доступа к устройству обычно появляются только тогда, когда это самое устройство занято другим соединением. Таковое также может возникнуть, если подключиться к устройству, но не освободить ресурсы (кто именно их не освободил - другой вопрос).

Comment: Дело в том, что я пробовал подключаться как из main-функции, так и из метода класса к разным видеокамерам. Из main всё прекрасно работало, и вот недавно решил переместить эту функциональность в метод, встретив вот эту проблему.

Comment: К сожалению, мало информации, чтобы что-то подсказать. В `main()` или в методе произвольного класса - разницы нет, должно работать одинаково. Обновите вопрос и приведите полный листинг минимального проекта, при котором происходит ошибка.

Comment: Дело в том, что там действительно ничего особо другого нет, относящегося к проблеме. Впрочем, попробую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, по прежнему в коде (см. обсуждение в комментариях к вопросу) не видно, где может быть ошибка. Тем не менее минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблемную ситуацию, должен выглядеть несколько иначе. Например, так.

```
class CaptureWrapper {
    public:
        CaptureWrapper() {}
        ~CaptureWrapper() {}

        bool open() {
            return _vid_cap.open(0);
        }

        void close() {
            if(_vid_cap.isOpened())
                _vid_cap.release();
        }    

    private:
        cv::VideoCapture _vid_cap;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    CaptureWrapper wrapper;
    if(wrapper.open() == false) {
        std::cout << "Failed!";
        return -1;
    }

    wrapper.close();

    return 0;
}
```

В том случае, если минимальный пример заработает, можно постепенно наращивать его функционалом, как то возможность выбора устройства по индексу или пути к видеофайлу, каждый раз проверяя корректность работы приложения. Таким образом станет возможно легко локализовать проблемное место в коде, если таковое вдруг появится.

Comment: Спасибо и на этом, буду пробовать ещё, добавлю ваши введения. Приведённый мной код действительно полностью показывает всё, что находится в окружении ошибки. То есть, дальше работа программы не идёт, так как при вызове `camera_open(...)` этот метод пытается сделать `camera.open(...)` (можно и без метода дополнительного, но я предпочёл ввести `try-catch`), и возникает проблема.

Я подумал, что дело может быть в каких-то тонкостях инициализации. Но именно `cv::VideoCapture::open(...)` же этим занимается. Это может быть багом OpenCV, странностями компилятора (MVSC) или чем-то ещё в этом духе?

Comment: Если и есть проблема в OpenCV (возможность странности в поведении компилятора можно не рассматривать априори), то это скорее следствие возможной несовместимости устройства и OpenCV. Но это довольно редкий случай, поскольку OpenCV чаще работает как обёртка над FFmpeg, а последний каких только чертей не поддерживает. Если у Вас минимальный пример не заработает, попробуйте `try-catch` прямо в `main()`, если не пробовали. Если же окажется, что там всё нормально, то это будет, мягко говоря, нонсенс.

Comment: Я уже говорил. Создание видеокамеры, её инициализация и закрытие прямо в `main` прекрасно работает. Более того, это работает, если создавать экземпляр класса `MyClass` в точке входа и через этот экземпляр там же запускать и прочее. А вот если делать всё изнутри класса, то - увы. Я столкнулся с этим только тогда, когда решил переместить в класс, в приватную зону, всё относящееся к компьютерному зрению, а в `main` оставалось примерно только это.

Comment: Тогда остаётся только вариант постепенного наращивания из минимального примера во что-то более функциональное. Сам факт размещения объекта `cv::VideoCapture` и его метода `open()` в `private` секции абсолютно ничего не меняет.